# Unable to add item to my sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, web-part, splistitem

I try to add an item to my sharepoint list from a custom web part. Is there any mistake in my code?

```
[WebMethod]
        public static string AjouterDemande()
        {
            SPList ListeDemandeConge = SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb.Lists["DEMANDE CONGÉ"];
            SPListItem ListItem = ListeDemandeConge.Items.Add();
            ListItem["CODE"] = code;
            ListItem["DEMANDEUR"] = Utilisateur.LoginName;
            ListItem["DATE DEMANDE"] = DateTime.Today.Date;
            ListItem["DATE FIN"] = EndDateD;
            ListItem["DATE DEPART"] = StartDateD;
            ListItem["DUREE"] = int.Parse(DayCount);
            ListItem["PREMIER RESPONSABLE"] = Employe.FirstSuperior.LoginName;
            ListItem["DEUXIEME RESPONSABLE"] = Employe.SecondSuperior.LoginName;
            ListItem["PRESENCE PRES"] = Boolean.Parse(FirstRespPresent);
            ListItem["SOLDE CONGE"] = Conge.SoldeAnneeConge;
            ListItem["MOIS"] = int.Parse(StartDateTab[1]);
            ListItem["ANNEE"] = int.Parse(StartDateTab[0]);
            ListItem["JOURS APPROUVEES"] = 0;
            ListItem.Update();
            ListeDemandeConge.Update();
            return "true";

        }
```

When I use F10 to process debugging step by step and get to my `listitem.update()`, it went out without giving any error.

Comment: display name work for me to get those colomns value

Comment: ListeDemandeConge.Update(); any reason for updating the List?

Comment: is there any other suggestion  !

Comment: Change the listitem variable name to avoid confusion.

Comment: i tried that and it give nothing, i think that the problem is in ListeDemandeConge.AddItem() because no item is added to the list after this instruction

Comment: i even create a new list to test add item it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try SPList.AddItem instead of Items.Add

However, I can't figure out why your code is not working! Below are some links for your reference

[List.AddItem() and List.Item.Add() … why two methods for same purpose](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/73285/list-additem-and-list-item-add-why-two-methods-for-same-purpose)
[SPList.Add() vs SPList.AddItem() SharePoint 2010](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/54958/splist-add-vs-splist-additem-sharepoint-2010)

Comment: it doesn't work also no item is added to list to be updated

Comment: is there any other solution ?

Comment: what is SPList.Items.Count before and after the execution of this code? do you see any possibility of issue with permissions?