# Best practice to add list item in SharePoint Server OM?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, best-practices, list-item

from the below codes, which one is best practice and performance wise also:-

**CASE 1:**

```
using (SPSite oSPsite = new SPSite("http://website url/"))
{
using (SPWeb oSPWeb = oSPsite.OpenWeb())
      {
            oSPWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

            // Fetch the List
            SPList list = oSPWeb.Lists["MyList"];

            //Add a new item in the List
            SPListItem itemToAdd = list.Items.Add();
            itemToAdd["Title"] = "Test Title";
            itemToAdd["Description"] = "Test Description";
            itemToAdd.Update();

            // Get the Item ID
            listItemId = itemToAdd.ID;

            // Update the List item by ID
            SPListItem itemToUpdate = list.GetItemById(listItemId);
            itemToUpdate["Description"] = "Changed Description";
            itemToUpdate.Update();

            // Delete List item
            SPListItem itemToDelete = list.GetItemById(listItemId);
            itemToDelete.Delete();

            oSPWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
       }
}
```

Reference: http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/Add-Update-and-Delete-List-Items-Programmatically-in-Sharepoint-372.php

**CASE 2:**

```
SPWeb mySite = SPContext.Current.Web;
SPListItemCollection listItems = mySite.Lists[TextBox1.Text].Items;

SPListItem item = listItems.Add();

item["Title"] = TextBox2.Text;
item["Stock"] = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox3.Text);
item["Return Date"] = Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox4.Text);
item["Employee"] = TextBox5.Text;

item.Update();
}
```

Reference: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms467435(v=office.14).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms467435%28v=office.14%29.aspx). There is no mention of allow unsafe updates in this code? Is that OK?

Comment: Was wondering why you won't use CSOM / JSOM?

Comment: What is the advantage>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`AllowUnsafeUpdates=true;` is not required to add/delete/update list items unless you are doing these operations in `Page_Load` or other Get methods. Both CASE 1 and CASE 2 does not look good in terms of best practice.
Problems with both case code:

Do not use `oSPWeb.Lists["MyList"];` instead use `oSPWeb.Lists.TryGetList("MyList1");`
Do not use `list.Items.Add();` instead use `list.AddItem();`

Always dispose objects (Best to use `using()`, done correctly in case 1, but try to avoid hard coded url if it is a webpart or user control etc)

Add null check for list object before using it.

Best practice code:

```
using (SPSite oSPsite = new SPSite("http://website url/"))//try not use hard code url unless no other option
            {
                using (SPWeb oSPWeb = oSPsite.OpenWeb())
                {
                    // Fetch the List
                    SPList list = oSPWeb.Lists.TryGetList("MyList1");
                    if (list != null)
                    {
                        //Add a new item in the List
                        SPListItem itemToAdd = list.AddItem();
                        itemToAdd["Title"] = "Test Title";
                        itemToAdd["Description"] = "Test Description";
                        itemToAdd.Update();

                        // Get the Item ID
                        listItemId = itemToAdd.ID;

                        // Update the List item by ID
                        SPListItem itemToUpdate = list.GetItemById(listItemId);
                        itemToUpdate["Description"] = "Changed Description";
                        itemToUpdate.Update();

                        // Delete List item
                        SPListItem itemToDelete = list.GetItemById(listItemId);
                        itemToDelete.Delete();
                    }
                }
            }
```

Always run sharepoint code analyser on your code.You can [download it here](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d3b2aaf7-0d6a-4995-a4e5-4153c57e3889)

Comment: cool.. Can you provide any reference article for this..if possible

Comment: Also, do a `new SPSite("http://website url/")` only if you are accessing list from another site. Otherwise for current site, `SPContext.Current.Web` is always a better choice.

Comment: @Nachiket best way to learn this is by running SPCAF(SharePoint Code analysis Framework) on your code. I have added link to download it in the answer.

Comment: @VardhamanDeshpande Also keep in mind that SPContext does not exist in PowerShell. So when you have code (like a feature) that you want to activate through PowerShell, don't use SPContext. Bad example because features have their SPSite/Web/Others in the featureproperties. But Still :).

Comment: Should note that to get lists by Title is not the best choice always, since end users could change the Title. I usually use an extension on SPWeb for "TryGetList". Something like this:  web.GetList(SPUtility.ConcatUrls(web.ServerRelativeUrl, "/Lists/MyList"))

Answer (score 2):

Both look same apart from the fact that `AllowUnsafeUpdates` is used in the second example. However, the better way of adding list items is `SPList.AddItem()` instead of `SPList.Items.Add()` See this for more explanation: [SPList.Add() vs SPList.AddItem() SharePoint 2010](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/54958/splist-add-vs-splist-additem-sharepoint-2010)

Answer (score 1):

A lot of things to note here:

- In case #1, you open new `SPSite`/`SPWeb` objects (resulting in a need for `AllowUnsafeUpdates`). You open new objects only in case you want to run code in an elevation section (or with System user token, with leads more or less to the same result).
- In both cases, you use `list.Items.Add();` witch is a very bad practice: you consumme SQL resources to read all records in the list (may be 1000s of items!), network between SP and SQL, and SP RAM to load all these items... `list.AddItem()` is definitely the way to go.
- You get access to the list with `oSPWeb.Lists["MyList"];` witch may fail if the list is renamed. The only correct way to get a list for sure, even if it's renamed is:

  oSPWeb.GetList(SPUrlUtility.CombineUrl(oSPWeb.Url, listUrl))

`listUrl` being the site-relative URL of the list (e.g. `Lists/Contacts`).